# React map only checks the last checkbox

Tags: reactjs

I have a 2 sets of unique checkboxes and each one has its own fields, and some of them are checked, so I would like to check the selected ones by default on page load, but  for some reason it only selects the last checkbox and ignores the first list

You can check it out here at [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-grass-qdz37c?file=/index.js)

```
import React, { Component, useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Checkbox, Pane, Label } from "evergreen-ui";

function ControlledCheckboxExample() {
  const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState(true);
  const [fieldchecked, setIsFieldChecked] = React.useState(false);
  const [editContactFields, setContactFields] = React.useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    loaddata();
  }, []);
  const loaddata = () => {
    let data = [
      {
        id: 1,
        label: "First Checkbox",
        type: "checkbox",
        selectedvalue: [
          {
            value: "one"
          },
          {
            value: "two"
          }
        ],
        hasvalue: true,
        tag: "UNIQUEONE",
        options: [
          {
            value: "one",
            text: "one"
          },
          {
            value: "two",
            text: "two"
          },
          {
            value: "three",
            text: "three"
          },
          {
            value: "four",
            text: "four"
          }
        ],
        visible: true
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        label: "Second Checkbox",
        type: "checkbox",
        selectedvalue: [
          {
            value: "five"
          }
        ],
        hasvalue: true,
        tag: "UNIQUETWO",
        options: [
          {
            value: "five",
            text: "five"
          }
        ],
        visible: true
      }
    ];
    setContactFields(data);
    data.map((field, index) => {
      if (field.type === "checkbox" && field.hasvalue == true) {
        setIsFieldChecked(false);
        let value = field.selectedvalue;
        let tag = field.tag;
        value.map((realvalue) => {
          let fieldvalud = realvalue.value;
          setIsFieldChecked((fieldchecked) => ({
            ...fieldchecked,
            [fieldvalud + tag]: !fieldchecked[fieldvalud + tag]
          }));
        });
      }
    });
  };

  const handlefieldchecked = (a, f) => {
    const fieldvalud = a;
    const tag = f;

    setIsFieldChecked((fieldchecked) => ({
      ...fieldchecked,
      [fieldvalud + tag]: !fieldchecked[fieldvalud + tag]
    }));
  };

  return (
    <Pane>
      {editContactFields.map((field) => (
        <Pane>
          <Label>
            {field.label} {field.required == true && "*"}
          </Label>
          {field.options.map((checkboxfield) => (
            <Checkbox
              name={field.tag + "[]"}
              id={field.tag}
              type={field.type}
              value={checkboxfield.value}
              label={checkboxfield.text}
              checked={fieldchecked[checkboxfield.value + field.tag]}
              required={field.required}
              onChange={(e) =>
                handlefieldchecked(checkboxfield.value, field.tag)
              }
            />
          ))}
        </Pane>
      ))}
    </Pane>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<ControlledCheckboxExample />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

When I remove the second set of checkboxes, it works like it should be, but as soon as I add it, it ignores the first ones.

Is there a way to make it work properly?

Comment: I'm not sure that is the problem, but you should *always* add a `key` attribute when you are iterating arrays inside the JSX part. `key={field.tag}` or something like that. Otherwise React won't know how to track update per individual item.

Comment: I tried right now and added a key but unfortunately it didn't do a thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're mapping over the `data` you reset `fieldchecked` with `setIsFieldChecked(false);` which will result in only having the values of the last iteration of the map.

```js
data.map((field, index) => {
  if (field.type === "checkbox" && field.hasvalue == true) {
    // setIsFieldChecked(false); => remove this
    let value = field.selectedvalue;
    let tag = field.tag;
    value.map((realvalue) => {
      let fieldvalud = realvalue.value;
      setIsFieldChecked((fieldchecked) => ({
        ...fieldchecked,
        [fieldvalud + tag]: !fieldchecked[fieldvalud + tag],
      }));
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Oh you're totally right thank you, you saved my day. I removed it and added it on top of the map and now it works perfectly. Thank you again.